# Error in passing filtered data to template. Reverse not found. 1 pattern(s) tried. What query should be used to avoid this error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a dynamic url that displays all the sub-courses in course. To do this I am passing the course name through the url and filtering the sub-courses to only send the ones for this course. However I cannot seem to find the correct query to filter and pass the data.

I attempted to follow the official Django documentation and search stack to find an answer but found nothing. My experimentation has also gotten me no results.

the view is

```
def subcourse(request, course):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        course = Course.objects.get(slug=course)
        subcourses = Subcourse.objects.all().filter(course=course)
        context = {'subcourses': subcourses}
        return render(request, 'subcourse.html', context)
```

and my models are:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/courses',
        null=True,
        blank=True
        )
    position = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Subcourse(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/subcourses',
        null=True,
        blank=True)
    position = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is the relevant part of my sub course.html template:

```
    {% for subcourse in subcourses %}
    <a href="{% url 'subcourse' lesson.slug %}">
        <div class="Training_types_cont">
            <img class="Training_types_img" src="{{subcourse.thumbnail.url}}">
            <span class="Training_types_txt"> {{subcourse.title}} </span>
        </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

the relevant url is:

```
path('training/<slug:course>', views.subcourse, name='subcourse')
```

and the current error message is

```
Reverse for 'subcourse' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['training/(?P<course>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

I have read through the documentation regarding queries and filters but cannot seem to find my error.

Comment: add your `subcourse.html` file too

Comment: added however the html is also being used for a different template where I do the same but do not filter the model. it also is not part of a dynamic url.

Comment: "subcourse.slug" instead "lesson.slug". That's what I said kkk